# Airflow 2.3 - Changing a task instance state as failed without raising

Tags: python-3.x, state, airflow-2.x, raise

Using task flow, let's say I have:

```
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)
def myDag():
    @task()
    def getData():
        try:
            result = something_that_might_fail()
            return result
        except HorribleException as error:
            context = get_current_context()
            context['task_instance'] = State.FAILED # Doesn't work
            return {"error": str(error)}

    @task()
    def transform(data_dict: dict):
        for data in data_dict:
            print(data)
        ...


    transform(getData())

run = myDag()
```

For monitoring purposes I want to mark the *getData* task failed but I still want to pass a result to *transform*. I tried to use the context to get access to the task instance state but it doesn't  seem to work. It seems there should be a better approach, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the status of the task, but not part of the task itself but in the other task. I guess that once you exit the "getdata" successfully then its state eventually is "success".

You can send info to "transform" task to change "getdata" and do it as follow :

```
@task()
def transform(data_dict: dict):
    context = get_current_context()
    dag_run: DagRun = context['dag_run']
    dag_run.dag.set_task_instance_state(
        task_id="getdata", state=TaskInstanceState.FAILED, run_id=dag_run.run_id,
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using xcom.pull in the next task instead of passing it with task flow. This way, if the first task fails, the next task get None on the pull. Your solution would work with task flow though, it's a good answer to my question. Thanks.